# How to make delayed function evaluate to zero

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction

I have a function

```
y[r_] := D[otherfunction[r],t] +  D[r,t];
```

where $r$ can pick up a time dependence depending on the problem. When it does not I am having issues as it's returning `0[1]` instead of `0`. Is this because of the delayed `:=` command? How to make it evaluate to zero when the time dependencies are lost?

Thanks

Comment: The whole setup is not really correct in terms of programming. You should never have function access anything that is not passed to it via its arguments. In your example, `otherfunction` and `t` are global. They should be instead be passed to the function via its arguments.  So your function should have been `y[r_,t_,f_]` where `f` is the other function. This is the right way to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have always to write the arguments of a function, even if it is a dummy argument. With this you would write:

```
y[r_] := D[f[r[t]], t] + D[r[t], t];
```

Now, if r does not depend on t, like:

```
r[t_]= const;
y[r[t]]

0
```

And for t depended r;

```
r[t_] = const  t;
y[r[t]]

const + const Derivative[1][f][const t]
```

And for any argument without explicite t dependence:

```
y[r]

0
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's shift our perspective to looking at a "time independent `r`" as "`r[t]` is constant for all `t`".  This naturally extends to a time **dependent** case where "`r[t]` is **not** constant for all `t`".  With this in mind, we can change `r` to `r[t]` and not lose any generality.

Then we can rewrite your expression as

```
y[r_] := D[otherfunction[r[t]], t] + D[r[t], t]
```

where `r` now needs to be given as a `Function`.  For example

```
y[Function[{t}, t^2]]
```

> 2 t + 2 t otherfunction'[t^2]

There are also the "syntactic" reasons why your implementation isn't doing what you want it to (as in @Daniel Huber's excellent answer), but this is another way of thinking about "what the code *means*".

Alternatively, you can also use the total derivative [`Dt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt.html) which has the documentation

> All quantities not explicitly specified as constants are assumed to depend on the [arguments]

So for your example

```
Dt[otherfunction[r], t] + Dt[r, t]
```

> Dt[r, t] + Dt[r, t] otherfunction'[r]

Comment: thank you for sharing your answer, if had more points would up vote you.